# Compiling large image source files under WPF / C# (possible Site of Origin solution?)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, resources, compilation

I am developing a Kinect application in C# using WPF under Visual Studio 2010 Express. The application requires a single Image control to switch between about 700 different source images, amounting to about 260 MB altogether. I did not think it would be too much, but when I make those 700 images resource files, when I try to publish (or just run) the application, the build fails, apparently due to lack of memory (I have 8 GB of RAM). It's the same for Content files. The application works just fine as long as I start it from code and read the images from a specified folder, though.

So I have been thinking about Site of Origin files. I have set Build Action to None and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always for all the image files and rebuilt the project. However the image files don't appear anywhere in the published application. I have tried setting the output path to different folders, but nothing seems to work.

So my question is, are Site of Origin files the right way to go, and if so, what am I doing wrong? Also, once I do manage to have them published along with the rest of the application, how exactly would I access them from code? (Yes, I know that is reversing the actual process – I just mean in principle. I haven't been able to find much on this – basically just [this](http://dotnet.learningtree.com/2011/12/28/dynamically-accessing-large-resource-files-in-xaml-at-runtime/), but it's for Visual Basic. I'd like to access them from C#, not XAML.)

Or, is there some other way to do this? Have I been doing something wrong when trying to use resource files initially?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [Content Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970494%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Content_Files) or you can do something similar to PC games: merge all your resource images in a single large file (you need to code a little application to create it).